# matrix operation using numpy pandas

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas

I am trying to test same example given on [Matrix search operation using numpy and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293881/matrix-search-operation-using-numpy-and-pandas)

on `3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:32:08 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux` with `python 2.7.3, numpy 1.9.2 and pandas 0.15.2`

For this small exammple :

```
ds1 = [[ 4, 13,  6,  9],
       [ 7, 12,  5,  7],
       [ 7,  0,  4, 22],
       [ 9,  8, 12,  0]]
ds2 = [[ 4,  1],
       [ 5,  3],
       [ 6,  1],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 8,  2],
       [ 9,  3],
       [12,  1],
       [13,  2],
       [22,  3]]

ds1= pd.DataFrame(ds1)
ds2= pd.DataFrame(ds2)
C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:, None] == ds2.values[:, 0])
print C
```

gives wrong result

```
(array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]), 
 array([ 0, 7, 2, 5, 3, 6, 1, 3, 3, 0, 8, 5, 4, 6]))
```

**Expected output is**

```
output = [[1, 2, 1, 3],
          [2, 1, 3, 2],
          [2, 0, 1, 3],
          [3, 2, 1, 0]]
```

and while working with large matrix values

```
ds1 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/9527bad750fbe75e072c/raw/ds1', sep=' ', header=None)
ds2 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/1692f1f76718c35e939f/raw/6f6b348ab0879b702e1c3c5e362e9d2062e9e9bc/ds2', header=None, sep=' ')
C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:, None] == ds2.values[:, 0])
print C
```

it gives

```
(1000, 1001) (4000, 2)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
```

instead of the replaced matrix value.

Any suggestion would be much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Anthony Lethuillier 's answer and I just guess the `IndexError` may be caused by different version. It seem's in @nlper 's situation, `C` is `(array([], dtype=int32),)` which means nothing found in `ds1.values.ravel()[:, None] == ds2.values[:, 0]`, and this is obviously different from @Anthony 's. Nothing found, thus `C` is a tuple which only contains 1 element, so an `IndexError` is triggered when you accessing `C[1]`.

This also works on my machine so I don't know why `C` is empty. I recommend you to print `ds1.values.ravel()` and `ds2.values[:, 0]` in detail and see why nothing equals.

Besides, I use python 2.7.9, numpy 1.9.2 and pandas 0.16.1

Answer (score 1):

The second array in C (array([ 0, 7, 2, 5, 3, 6, 1, 3, 3, 0, 8, 5, 4, 6]) gives you the positions of the values you want to replace in ds1.

So you have to replace the values in ds1.values.ravel() with the index of the first array of C with the values in ds2 with the index of the second array of C

Here is the code that gives the right output for the small example :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds1 = [[ 4, 13,  6,  9],
      [ 7, 12,  5,  7],
      [ 7,  0,  4, 22],
      [ 9,  8, 12,  0]]

ds2 = [[ 4,  1],
       [ 5,  3],
       [ 6,  1],
       [ 7,  2],
       [ 8,  2],
       [ 9,  3],
       [12,  1],
       [13,  2],
       [22,  3]]

ds1= pd.DataFrame(ds1)
ds2= pd.DataFrame(ds2)

C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:, None] == ds2.values[:, 0])

ds1_new = ds1.values.ravel()

ds1_new[C[0]]=ds2.values[C[1], 1]

ds1_new = ds1_new.reshape(4,4)

print(ds1_new)

ds1 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/9527bad750fbe75e072c/raw/ds1', sep=' ', header=None)
ds2 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/1692f1f76718c35e939f/raw/6f6b348ab0879b702e1c3c5e362e9d2062e9e9bc/ds2', header=None, sep=' ')

C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:, None] == ds2.values[:, 0])

ds1_new = ds1.values.ravel()

ds1_new[C[0]]=ds2.values[C[1], 1]

ds1_new = ds1_new.reshape(1000,1001)

print(ds1_new)
```

Gives the following output :

```
[[1 2 1 3]
 [2 1 3 2]
 [2 0 1 3]
 [3 2 1 0]]
[[  1.   1.   1. ...,   1.   1.  nan]
 [  1.   1.   1. ...,   0.   1.  nan]
 [  1.   0.   1. ...,   1.   0.  nan]
 ..., 
 [  1.   1.   1. ...,   0.   1.  nan]
 [  1.   0.   1. ...,   1.   1.  nan]
 [  1.   1.   1. ...,   0.   1.  nan]]
```

Comment: could you please add description for lines, for large matrix I added `ds1_new = ds1_new.reshape(1000,1001)` but I am getting `IndexError: tuple index out of range` at `ds1_new[C[0]]=ds2.values[C[1], 1]`

Comment: Edited my answer to include the compete code for the big matrices

Comment: thanks for help, but still I am getting error for the same code for large matrices `line 39, in <module>
    ds1_new[C[0]]=ds2.values[C[1], 1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: It works when I use Python2 so it doesn't come from there, my version of Panda is 0.16 so it's maybe that, I'll try tonight on my Ubuntu computer

Comment: Just tried it with a Ubuntu with pandas 0.14, python 2.7.9 and numpy 1.9.1 and it works, maybe try updating re installing pandas/numpy/scipy. Have you tried with Python3 ?